# How to use threads for collision detection simultaneously for different pair of objects

Tags: java, applet

I found many questions regarding collision detection and I have created an efficient enough method which will detect if the two given pair of objects collide or not. The thing is, when I increase the number of objects from 2 to 20, suddenly the algorithm stops working correctly. For example, if the particle one hits particle ten, then particle ten in turn skips the other objects and collides directly to the wall.

The reason behind it is that when, say, particle one is actually colliding with particle ten, my algorithm is not checking for collision between them, but is checking for other pairs.

The solution according to me, would be to run the collision detection method for each pair simultaneously. Now for that I need to pass Particle one and Particle Two to each thread where One and Two are the objects for which collision is to be detected.

Here's the pseudo code:

```
private double isColliding(Particle One, Particle Two) { 
     //Collision Detection Mechanism
     //Returns 0 if no collision
     //Otherwise returns a double between 0 and 1 
     //used to clip the velocity vector so that it stops right before collision
}
```

So, what I want is to know how to convert the above method to run on different threads for different pair of objects....

Also, is there any other way this could be done.......

Note.... this above method doesn't change any values of particle one or two, so can be used asynchronously....

Comment: If you do this all async, how are you going to recapture the results and apply it to your objects? I made a bouncing balls simulation a few years ago, thru which I realized that trying to have objects "moving themselves" ie using multiple threads was a disaster.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I think you are misunderstanding, what I meant was there's nothing like critical sections in this isColliding() method and all I'm interested is in the return value of this method. Also, this method doesn't move objects it just tells me if the velocity vector should be clipped or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the lighty version of threading ^^

```
    double result;
    Thread t = new Thread(){
      public void run(){
        result = isColliding(aParticle, aParticle);
      }
    };
    t.start();

    t.join();
```

The join lets the mainthread wait for the thread t to finish.
Put this in a 2-dim for loop to iterate over every particle pair with a result array and a thread array to call join on at the end. And you got what wantet.

BUT there is no point in trying to make sth. work in multiple threads, if its not running in a single one ^^
So actually my answer to you is. You did sth. wrong. You should fix your collisionDetection function. If you want help, you should provide us more code.

Comment: Worked great, now each and every collision is detected. However the applet response time sucks!!! Any suggestions for that...

Comment: Seems like you were right, I was not using my boolean correctly, the problem is solved. Thank you....